# Get Active Dialog from Microsoft bot framework composer

Tags: c#, botframework, bot-framework-composer, adaptive-dialogs

I need to get the active dialog from Microsoft bot framework composer, when I open the project with visual studio and start debugging, in the ComposerBot.cs - OnTurnAsync() method, I didn't find any way to get the active dialog, it always returns the root dialog Id, Is there any way to get the active dialog? how the composer know which dialog should initialize next?

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this part and I didn't find a way to get the active dialog but if we create dc in composerbot.cs we can get the last intent and see the flow